# How to make a boxplot with subset values and all values on the same plot?

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I am working with base R plot.

I want to create a boxplot that includes both subset values and all values on the same plot. The key is it must be in base R plot.

```
Party <- rep(c("Rep", "Dem", "Ind"), 50)
Values <- sample(1:100, size = length(Party), replace = T)

hw <- data.frame(Party, Values)

#Plot 1
boxplot(hw$Values, 
        col=c("green"),
        xlab = "All Respondents")
#Plot 2
boxplot(hw$Values~hw$Party, 
        col=c("blue", "purple", "red"),
        xlab = "Partisan Respondents")
```

I essentially would like plot 1 and plot 2 to be combined into one plot.

Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple way to add all values group.

```
library(dplyr)   # edited line

hw2 <- hw %>% 
  bind_rows(hw %>% mutate(Party = "ALL"))

boxplot(Values ~ Party, data = hw2,
        col = c("gray60", "blue", "purple", "red"),
        xlab = "Partisan Respondents")
```

Comment: library(dplyr), right? Thanks a million! I appreciate the help!

Comment: Yes, sorry for the missing.